# HTML Email - Outlook 2007 border on img tag is missing

Tags: css, border, html-email, outlook-2007

I am working on an HTML email and having some css style issues in Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013.

I have two images in a td cell and 1 of them i want a vertical border divider to separate them. I placed a border right on the first (left image) and it works in all clients/browsers by Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013.

Here is the code i am using:

```
 <tr>
     <td bgcolor="#673695" style="color:#ffffff;padding:14px 0 14px 14px;text-align:left;border-collapse: collapse;">
         <img src="lowreslogo.png" border="0" width="130" style="border-right:1px solid #a377cd;padding-right:20px;"  align="left">
         <img src="email_logo.png" border="0" width="150" align="left" style="padding-top:7px;">
     </td>
 </tr>
```

I have run this through litmus.com and need some help with these couple of clients that are left. I cant modify the two images to have a border built in just as a side note...

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007 does not support CSS `border` on `<img>` elements - see [the report](http://www.email-standards.org/clients/microsoft-outlook-2007/) from the Email Standards Project for Outlook 2007. There is a more detailed example from the same site [here](http://www.email-standards.org/blog/entry/outlook-2007-doesnt-show-image-borders/).

So it seems that the [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx) documentation is incorrect as it states that the `<img>` element [does support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Word2007MailHTMLandCSS_Full) `border-right`.

I suggest wrapping the first image in a `<span>` and styling that instead. Sorry I can't test as I don't have Outlook.

Comment: Yah i saw this suggestion before and it didnt work on my end... meaning the span suggestion

Comment: Did you try wrapping in `<span style="display:inline-block;padding-right:20px;border-right:1px solid #a377cd;">`?

Comment: Yes i tried this exact technique and it doesn't work for those select Outlook versions...

Answer (score 0):

You are also declaring border=0 in html on the same image. Not sure if that is overriding your css declaration in this case.

You could try setting that to 1 (or removing it altogether). If you set it to 1, you'd have to set the color on the 3 other border sides to match the background so they are effectively invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap those 2 images in a table like below. Some extra code but will fix rendering issue.

```
<tr>
     <td bgcolor="#673695" style="color:#ffffff;padding:14px 0 14px 14px;text-align:left;border-collapse: collapse;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300" style="color:#ffffff">
            <tr>
                <td width="130"><img src="lowreslogo.png" border="0" width="130" alt="" style="display: block;" /></td>
                <td width="19"></td>
                <td width="1" bgcolor="#a377cd"><td>
                <td width="150" style="padding-top:7px;"><img src="email_logo.png" border="0" width="150" alt="" style="display: block;" /></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </td>
</tr>
```